# Guidance on missing() in R

Tags: r, function

Suppose a function, **G**, takes two arguments; **a** and **b:** `G(a = some number, b = some number)`.

Now **two situations** (*wondering what commands  to use in each case?*):

1- if a user puts `G(b = some number)`, will the `if(missing(a)){do this}` recognize the **complete absence** of `a` argument?    *AND more importantly*:

2- if a user puts `G(a =, b = some number)`, still will the `if(missing(a)){do this}` recognize `a =` but **lack** of `some number` in front of it?

Comment: i believe the answer to 1) is **YES** and the 2) will produce an error, can't have an assigned `=` sign hanging out in the arguments of a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the function as below doesn't throw an error in both the cases:

```
ch <- function(a=NA,b=NA){ if(is.na(a)) return(b) else( return(a+b)) }

> ch(b=2)
[1] 2
> ch(a=,b=2)
[1] 2
```

Comment: On a related thing, suppose in the case of complete absence of `a` I need to produce a message for the user like:  `if(missing(a)) {message(cat("\n","Note: Now you're doing Power Analysis for a **Paired- or One-sample t-test**."))}`, R is giving the following error message `argument "a" is missing, with no default`, what can I do?

Comment: If you define the function with a default value of `a` as `NA` in the function there shouldn't be any error.